# Using Java application launcher

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-construction, javac, java-launcher

I have class `Hello`. I have successfully compiled the .class file from it and placed it into dir/subdir directory and have assigned it the dir.subdir package in its code. And I want to run it from the command line with `java` command.

I have run it with command: **java dir/subdir/Hello** and it ran successfully! But I read in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) that it should be done with simply fully-qualified class name. I tried to execute: **java dir.subdir.Hello** and it ran successfully too!!

Which of these ways is sound approach and more correctly? What does each of them specifically means? What is their fundamental difference?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the dotted form, but not because of platform compatibility.

The argument `dir/subdir/Hello` is valid to use here because Java's default `ClassLoader` implementation processes it correctly. However, not all `ClassLoader` implementations support this. You should use the dotted form because according to the documentation in `ClassLoader.loadClass` names are supposed to be [binary names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#name). The JLS defines binary names in [JLS 13.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1), item 1:

> The class or interface must be named by its binary name, which must meet the following constraints:
>
> - The binary name of a top level type is its canonical name.
> - The binary name of a member type consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by `$`, followed by the simple name of the member.
> - The binary name of a local class consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by `$`, followed by a non-empty sequence of digits, followed by the simple name of the local class.
> - The binary name of an anonymous class consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by `$`, followed by a non-empty sequence of digits.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic class or interface is the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by `$`, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic method is the binary name of the type declaring the method, followed by `$`, followed by the descriptor of the method as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by `$`, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic constructor is the binary name of the type declaring the constructor, followed by `$`, followed by the descriptor of the constructor as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by `$`, followed by the simple name of the type variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using the package name (with dots) is better, since it is cross-platform (remember that Windows uses `\`) and is closer to what you would need if your program is in a jar file (where `Main-Class` has to be specified as a class name).

Comment: But if I am sure that it is not in a jar? Has Linux  differences  for example?

Comment: When you launch a Java program from a jar, the class isn't specified at the command line but rather in the `Manifest` of the jar as the `Main-Class`. It's better to use the dot-based name for consistency.

Comment: There is no cross-platform problem here at all. Using `/` is required on both Windows and Linux, you can't use `\\`

Answer (score 0):

You should always use dots as this works for all OS (win/unix/mac). Package is nothing but directory Structure which in windows is treated with a slash (/) , so java is able to run your program without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use dots for it is then able for cross platform running. Mac/WIndows/Linux